# Xcode 13 stuck on indexing after new update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode13

i have clear derive data folder, clean, and rebuild project again but still stuck after indexing and not able to run the project on simulator and real devices.

Comment: i am also getting the same issue after Xcode 13 update

Comment: @NomanUmar any idea what's the issue

Comment: A comment since I am unsure whether that would fix it, but did you try cleaning Xcode Cache (`~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`) as well?

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on Flutter and faced same issue no Xcode 14.2.

Turned out there's no Scheme selected, maybe a cuase of my working on many flavors.

Anyway, try to clean your project `cmd+shift+k`, it will show the error message.
Just select a scheme.

Then you're good to go.